# over 20.000 taxonomy category issue - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm using wordpress. And have inserted over 20.000 product categories but now the page where I'm showing all categories is down and not available.

Even in the backend - after some amount of categories, I can't see rest. And I see following errors:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 
bytes) in /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 273

Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in class-wp-terms-list-table.php on line 273

PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 0
```

I tried to increase php.ini settings to these:

```
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 3000
```

But no luck. What can be the issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you ever need to list all 20.000 product categories in one go? If you have that many, use paging/filter/search/infinit scroll or similar instead.

Comment: the issue is that they are not even showing in the backend where there is a pagination @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I'm confused. You said that you have a page where you show _all_ the categories? And what do you mean by "not even showing in the backend"? How are you trying to show them in the backend? Using paging means that you don't fetch all the categories from the database at once, but only a subset.

Comment: I mean in the taxonomy category page in the admin panel (edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product-category&post_type=product-items) @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Oh. You're talking about the Admin? So it's Wordpress that can't show them in the Admin?

Comment: it is showing first some amount of categories and then I see the errors I mentioned above @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Try adding: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', 1024M')` in your `wp-config.php`. You can play around with the amount of memory to find what works (if that setting still works). WP have an habit of overruling some of the PHP.ini settings with it's own settings.

Comment: Tried to do but still same. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I think you have to make pagination with custom queries , limited by a range

Comment: can you please show me some example? And if I do something like this for frontend, so what I will do for backend? @Fky

Comment: @aidaghazaryan https://wordpress.org/plugins/malinky-ajax-pagination/

Answer (score 1):

WoW. Thats a lot! In terms of wordpress you slowly killing your server.
I would suggest few things.

1. Move to standalone server (linode/digital ocean) right now provide good solutions for a reasonable amount of money.
2. Tnink on implementing caching, i also would suggest inmemory cache like memcached or redis, implementation for both exists in wordpress.org/plugins directory.
3. Rising memory limin in wordpress domain are done in next way. You need to define amount of memory you want to use in your wp-config.php. e.g.

   define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
4. time limit can be done in next way (also in wp-config), but i would suggest to fix issu in other way (impleneting cache)

   @ini_set( 'max_execution_time', 0 );
   @set_time_limit( 0 );
5. Please also consider way of changing your taxonomy to tags (if it doesn't require heirarchy), and use normal way to see your categories. For example Getting a list of categories in WordPress its triggering 3 tables (joins etc).
6. The other way of solving issue can be changing SQL via wordpress filter (but in ca case of get_terms it's a bit hard to implement in pure WordPress way)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get categories by pure SQL query (instead of wordpress function like get_terms).

Comment: can you please show me some example? @Tomasz Winter